# Issue with an ant-style pattern include and the maven-failsafe-plugin

Tags: maven, ant, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am desperately trying to get the maven failsafe plugin to run my integration tests.

I have configured the plugin as follows:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>failsafe-itest</id>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/integration/**</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I do have one integration test in the following package:

```
com.bignibou.tests.integration.repository.advertisement
```

However, mvn-failsafe-plugin **does not pick it up**.

*What is wrong with my include syntax?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/integration/**</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>failsafe-itest</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/integration/**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Sorted the issue.

However, I have to run the plugin itself with `mvn failsafe:integration-test` in order to run integration-test only and shortcircuit the unit-tests!